# Unexpected behavior of Laravel 5.4 pluck after migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mysql-8.0

### Introduction

> ##### **Please:** Look at the **Update** and the **Conclusion** at the end below first.

I have [laravel-5.4](/questions/tagged/laravel-5.4) app that runs fine on the following software configurations:

> - Kubuntu 20.04
> - PHP 7.4.29 from Onrej PPA
> - Apache, installed from the distro repos. Using **mod_php**
> - Laravel 5.4
> - MySQL 5.7 runs from Docker container.

I migrated this app to new OS, Kubuntu **22.04**, (I have dual boot on my PC), by copying all the project's files except, **vendor** and **node_modules** then I used composer to restore all required dependencies. The software configurations becomes:

> - Kubuntu **22.04**
> - PHP 7.4.29 from Onrej PPA > *The same*
> - Apache, installed from the distro repos. version 2.4.52 Using **FPM/FastCGI**
> - Laravel 5.4 > *The same*
> - MySQL ver 8.0.28 installed from the OS repos.

In the migrated app, I had to add `modes` directive to `config/database.php` in MySQL connection data to prevent the following fatal error:

> dev.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
> violation: 1231 Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of
> 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' in
> /home/user/www/app2-vn/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:105

Like the following:

```
'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'app2'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user1'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'P@55v0'),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true, //true
            'engine' => null,
            'timezone'  => '+02:00',
            'version'  => 8,
            'modes'  => [
          /*  'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',*/
           /* 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',*/
          /*  'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',*/
           /* 'NO_ZERO_DATE',*/
           /* 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',*/
           /* 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',*/
        ],
        ],
```

**By the way**, as shown above, an empty `modes` just fine to make the application works!

### The Issue

I have used pluck like the following:

```
$eqtypes = \App\Eqtype::get()->pluck('title','id');
dd($eqtypes,\App\Eqtype::get());
```

In the original app, it works fine with output:

```
Collection {#1279 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    1 => 'Mold'
    2 => 'Plank'
    3 => 'Neck'
  ]
}
```

**But** in the migrated app it returns null for the keys values:

```
Collection {#1279 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    1 => null
    2 => null
    3 => null
  ]
}
```

I am very confused, the same code base, the same PHP version and the same framework version, but different result!
I tried to look for any compatibility issue between Laravel 5.4 and MySQL 8, but I could not find anything. **What do you think the cause of this issue?**

## Update:

It looks like dependency issue, after replacing `vendor` directory generated by composer, with the `vendor` of original app by copying it directly, it works fine as expected.

I have translation model package called `Dimsav\Translatable\TranslatableServiceProvider::class,` I think it causes some model values to be null in English and I don't remember if I modified it to allow default fallback translation that returns the default string or not. [This is an issue](https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable/issues/409) I submitted there from Oct. 2017 and I think my original app vendor has hard code modification that I have suggested there.

## Conclusion

The issue is not related to the framework, PHP, or the database. It is missing hard coded a package's class.

Comment: does `dd(\App\Eqtype::get());` returns the same output on both apps?

Comment: @aceraven777  yes, the two are the same.

Comment: In the migrated app database, is the did you check if the `title` has values?

Comment: In the migrated app can you delete the `vendor` directory and then running `composer update`

Comment: @aceraven777 In the migrated app the `title` value is defined in the table. However, the direct selection of them in the app does not return value i.e empty string.

Comment: @aceraven777 It looks like dependency issue. I deleted the `vendor` of migrated app, but I copied it again from the original app. It worked fine. When I run composer first time, I got some message about compatibility issues and abundant packages, but I could not able to find where is that log.